# FL_Window missing a ;

Tags: c++, user-interface, fltk

I installed then built and compiled the FLTK library for GUI use so I can follow along with Bjarnes book,

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eSOPWQ1n6U

anyway I put the include files in the GL and FL in the ***2017/VC/tools/14.12.25827/include folder and the lib files need in 2017/VC/tools/14.12.25827/lib/x86/
and 2017/VC/tools/14.12.25827/lib/x64 allthough I will be only using it when developing 32 bit projects***

so I then added a new cpp file to an empty windows project,

I added fltk.lib into the additional dependencies for the linker in the project build settings

here is the dependencies kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(fltk.lib)

I then set the code generation under the c++ tab and runtime library to Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)as instructed

but I am getting a strange error(s)

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'hi'    Project5    c:\users\user\source\repos\project5\project5\hey.cpp    9
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  Project5    c:\Users\User\source\repos\Project5\Project5\hey.cpp    9
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3861   'hi': identifier not found  Project5    c:\users\user\source\repos\project5\project5\hey.cpp    9

```
#include <FL/Fl.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.h>


    int main(){

        FL_WINDOW hi(20, 20, "hey");

        return 0;
    }
```

**update

I tried

```
#include <FL/Fl.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.h>


int main() {

    Fl_Window wd(12, 12, "hey");

    return 0;
}
```

I used the class name instead of the macro but now I am getting two more errors

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int,int,char const *)" (??0Fl_Window@@QAE@HHPBD@Z) referenced in function _main Project8    C:\Users\User\source\repos\Project8\Project8\Source.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Fl_Window::~Fl_Window(void)" (??1Fl_Window@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main Project8    C:\Users\User\source\repos\Project8\Project8\Source.obj 1

Comment: I tried the following int main() {

 Fl_Window *window = new FL_Window(20, 20, "wont work");

 return 0;
}

but still seems to be giving me an error saying it expected a type specifier

Comment: I am sorry it should be `Fl_Window` not `FL_WINDOW` because `c++` is case sensitive. http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/basics.html

Comment: `%(fltk.lib)` is not correct.

Comment: Also its better to copy errors from the Output Tab than the errors tab since the error is in a better text format.

Comment: What is %fltk.lib% set to in your environment?

Comment: Please don't edit your own question to remove its entire content. If you no longer think it's useful, you can delete it. Or you can add a comment discussing whatever problems it has.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fl_Window* hi = new Fl_Window(20,20,"hey")
```

should work.

(looking at the makeWindow() function that can be seen at 4:30 in that video)

Answer (score 0):

as drescherjm mentioned the dependencies were in the wrong format

%(fltk.lib)  // wrong

I should have deleted that and just added fltk.lib